# Why do function pointers exist as long as they act similar to functions themselves?

Tags: c, function, pointers, gcc, reference

I know that there is a similar topic, but those answers don't clarify what I want to find out. Thus, as long as from the excerpt below one can notice that a function and the reference to that function behave in the same way, what is the point in having both function variable and function pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(){ return 0;}

int main() {
    printf("%p\n",f);
    printf("%p\n",&f);
    printf("%p\n",f + 1);
    printf("%p\n",&f + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, both f and &f could be passed as parameters for other functions.

Comment: Isn't this the same quesiton you asked earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041581/what-is-the-purporse-of-the-function-pointers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purporse of the function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66041581/what-is-the-purporse-of-the-function-pointers)

Comment: As I said there, there's no purpose to use `&f`, it's the same as `f`.

Comment: Yep, and it is still not clear for me why do I need both pointers to functions as long as they act identically like functions themselves.

Comment: I agree with you @Barmar, but, nevertheless, they still are.

Comment: You don't *need* them. But there's no other sensible meaning for `&f`, so it means the same thing.

Comment: Well, so why the compiler allows the presence of  &f?

Comment: Note that standard C says that arithmetic on function pointers is undefined — the `f + 1` and `&f + 1` are both undefined behaviour.  GCC provides a definition.  The incremented pointer is useless; you can't use it to call the function.  You can also use `*f` (and `**f`, etc).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not only undefined, it's a constraint violation. Meaning that a conforming compiler must give a diagnostic. Turns out neither gcc nor clang are conforming compilers unless you add `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. icc is not conforming in any mode so I guess it's just plain bad.

Comment: C11 [§6.5.6 Additive operators ¶2, ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p2).  GCC doesn't complain unless you force it to.  Unfortunately, people do not realize that GCC does not implement standard C.

Comment: `printf("%p\n",f);` is not specified correct way to print a function pointer.  `printf("%p\n",(void*)f);` is better, yet `(void*)f` may lose information as the function pointer may be wider than the `void*`.  C lacks a nice way to certainly print a function pointer.

Comment: TL;DR There is nothing wrong with function-pointer _variables,_ on the other hand, function-pointer _literals_ are rather lame for historical/compatibility reasons, this can be summarized whith this equation: `&main==*main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function pointers are necessary when you want a variable to refer to a particular function.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo1(void)
{
    printf("foo1\n");
}

void foo2(void)
{
    printf("foo2\n");
}

int main()
{
    void (*f)(void) = foo1;
    f();
    f = foo2;
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo1
foo2
```

If you attempted to do this:

```
void f(void) = foo1;
```

It would be invalid syntax.  And if you removed the initializer:

```
void f(void);
```

You would have a *function declaration*.

Comment: Thanks, I got the point. Also, could you tell me please, why the compiler does not allow void f(void) = foo1; ?

Comment: @pauk Variables can be initialized or not.  Without the initializer, you don't have a variable but a declaration of a function existing elsewhere.  Function bodies can't be instantiated inline.

Answer (score 5):

`f` and `&f` mean the same thing, so there's no need to use `&f`.

But the language designers decided not to make it invalid for some reason, so you have this redundant syntax.

Comment: So, it is kind of compiler design "bug/leakage"?

Comment: Even more, why do I need the concept of pointer to function, when a variable which is written this way: void fun(int); behaves like void (*fun)(int); ?

Comment: Function pointers are useful as variables that can refer to different functions dynamically.

Comment: It's analogous to the difference between arrays and pointers. Arrays are defined statically, pointers can be reassigned dynamically.

Comment: In order to understand better, could you give me an example where pointers to functions are a "must", please?

Comment: Look at the `qsort()` function. One of the arguments is a pointer to the comparison function, since this can be different for different arrays.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a "function variable".

A function "decays" into a pointer to a function whenever used in an expression. The only exception to that rule is when it is used together with the `&` operator in an expression. Then it does not decay but gives the function address in the form of a function pointer.

Therefore `f` and `&f` are both identical function pointers in your printf statement. As for the rationale why, it's probably just to keep them consistent with the behavior of arrays, which also decay using similar rules. `array` vs `&array` also give the same address.

As for why arrays decay to pointers in the first place, that's just how the language was designed. Dennis Ritchie who invented C didn't want to store addreses or sizes together with arrays (as was done in the ancient predecessor B language) and therefore he came up with this way instead.

`f + 1` is pointer arithmetic on a function pointer and doesn't make any sense, like your compiler told you when it refused to compile the posted code.

Comment: Nope, the compiler compiled that piece of code.

Comment: Note that `array` and `&array` give the same address, but they have different types. But `f` and `&f` have the same type.

Comment: @pauk Then it is not compliant. If you use gcc, it goes into non-C mode by default, which isn't helpful for C programmers in general and beginners in particular. Compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Specifically, this makes gcc non-compliant: (C17 6.5.6) "Constraints.
For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
pointer to a complete object type". A function pointer is not a pointer to an object type.

Comment: A function is _called_ and so is always an address. Therefore a function as used in an expression (without calling it) is the same as the address of the function.

Answer (score 2):

There are historical reasons for the somewhat weird behavior of the unary `&` and unary `*` operators on functions and function pointers, and it is all to do with adding convenience while retaining backwards compatibility for old code.

Prior to the standardization of the C language, it was necessary to apply the `&` operator to a function to convert it to a function pointer, and it was necessary to apply the `*` operator to a function pointer in order to to convert it to something of the corresponding function type that can be called. For example:

```
/* K&R style function pointer example. */
int func();  /* external function declaration */

int foo()
{
    int (*fp)(); /* function pointer variable */
    int val;

    fp = &func;  /* assign address of function func to function pointer fp */
    val = (*fp)(42); /* dereference and call function pointer fp */
    return val;
}
```

On standardization of the C language, the "function call" operation `( params... )` no longer operates on a *function*, it operates on a *function pointer*. However, because it would be inconvenient to apply the `&` operator to a function to convert it to a function pointer that can be called (i.e. calling a function `func` as `(&func)(42)` would be inconvenient), an expression of function type (such as the identifier from a function declaration) is automatically converted to a function pointer value that can be called (i.e. as `func(42)`), except when it is the operand of the unary `&`, `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operators. This means that a function pointer variable such as `int (*fp)(int);` can be called directly as `fp(42)`. It also means that for a function `func`, the expressions `func` and `(&func)` are equivalent.

Another example of an expression of function type (the standard defines the term *function designator* to mean an expression of function type) results from applying the unary `*` operator or the array subscripting operator `[ index ]` to a function pointer. This means that the old, pre-standard way of calling a function pointed to by a function pointer variable still works the same as it always did. For example, in the call `(*fp)(42)`, the function pointer value of `fp` is converted by the unary `*` operator to an expression of function type, but the expression of function type (a *function designator*) is automatically converted back to an expression of function pointer type. This means that all the following (and similar) ways of calling a function `func` are effectively equivalent:

```
func(42);
(&func)(42);
(*func)(42);
func[0](42);
(&*&*&*&*&func)(42);
(*&*&*&*&*func)(42);
```

For a function pointer variable `fp` the following and similar ways of calling the function are effectively equivalent:

```
fp(42);
(*fp)(42);
(&*fp)(42);
fp[0](42);
(*&*&*&*&*fp)(42);
```

Note that `(&fp)(42)` for function pointer variable `fp` is not a valid function call because `&fp` is a *pointer* to a function pointer and the function call operation only works on function pointers.

For standard C, the previous K&R style function pointer example can be rewritten as the following:

```
/* New style function pointer example. */
int func(int);  /* external function declaration */

int foo(void)
{
    int (*fp)(int); /* function pointer variable */
    int val;

    fp = func;  /* assign pointer to function func to function pointer fp */
    val = fp(42); /* call function pointer fp */
    return val;
}
```

As to the point of having variables (or parameters) of function pointer type, they have their uses as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out: `&f` and `f` are the same thing: when assigning `f`, or passing it as an argument, much like an array, the value you're passing/assigning is the address of (pointer to) the function.

If the question you're asking is *"Why are there function pointers"*, then you might want to consider this:

Say you're writing a library like GTK. You'll want the users of said library to be able to handle stuff like a button being clicked. This is done by allowing the user to pass in a function pointer. The pointer will point to the function they want to be called when a button is clicked. Simplest example: A GTK window with a button to quit the application:

```
    g_signal_connect(
        G_OBJECT(close_button),
        "clicked",
        G_CCALLBACK(close_window_cb),
        G_OBJECT(sub_window));
```

I'm basically telling GTK that, if a the object `close_button` is clicked, there's a callback function I want to have called. This callback is passed in as a function pointer. I'm also telling GTK to pass a pointer to `sub_window` as the second argument, so my function can close the window (destroy the widget).

The callback itself is very simple, and looks like this:

```
void close_window_cb(GtkWidget *w, gpointer window)
{
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}
```

You may think it'd be easier to just bind `gtk_widget_destroy` to the event, but what if I want to log something, or perform some other actions?

```
void close_window_cb(GtkWidget *w, gpointer window)
{
    printf("Button %s was clicked", gtk_widget_get_name(w));
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(window));
}
```

Without supporting user-defined callback functions, that'd be a hassle to implement.

### TL;DR

You don't *need* function pointers, but they are quite useful in quite a lot of situations.

Comment: Thanks, it clarified my perception about function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A function pointer is a *variable* that refers to a function.  The concept is useful in a number of scenarios.  C is statically linked, every regular function call is resolved to a fixed address assigned by the linker.  Function pointers allow decisions about which function will be called to be made at run-time.

Some examples:

- The standard library `qsort()` uses a function pointer to enable it to operate on arbitrary object types rather then requiring a separate function for every type of object you might want to sort.
- Interrupt handlers can be function pointers-written to the interrupt vector table, allowing you to dynamically install a n interrupt handler at run-time.
- It can simplify command parsers or menu handlers by replacing large switch-case or if-else if-else constructs with a look-up table or associative map.
- Event handlers.  For example a library may generate an event that requires a user defined handler written independently of the library. The POSIX `signal()` function for example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the `&` operator on a function designator is redundant, as `f` and `&f` evaluate to the same value *and type* (unlike arrays).  I suspect it's there more for consistency's sake than anything else.

---

Function pointers themselves have a number of uses.

They allow you to pass a function as an argument to another function for that function to execute (a.k.a. a *callback*).  The canonical example is the standard library function `qsort`:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

`qsort` calls the function pointed to by `compar` to determine how to order the elements of the array.  You can change the ordering just by passing different callbacks.

The few C-based GUI frameworks I have experience with had callbacks out the wazoo.

Function pointers allow you to add functionality to your application at runtime by loading a shared library:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
...
void *libhandle = dlopen( "libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL );
...
int (*do_something)(void) = dlsym( libhandle, "some_function_name" );
if ( do_something )
{
  int x = do_something();
  ...
}
```

They allow you to attach a behavior to an object - for example, I can attach a comparison function to a list object that allows me to control the ordering of the list (similar to passing the `compar` function to `qsort`):

```
struct node {
  data_t data; // for some arbitrary data type
  struct node *next;
};

struct list {
  struct node *head;
  int (*compar)( const data_t, const data_t );
};
...
void insert( struct list *l, data_t value )
{
  struct node *new = new_node( value ); // allocates node and assigns data
  struct node *cur = l->head, *prev = NULL;
  while ( l->compar( cur->data, new->data ) <= 0 )
  {
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  new->next = cur;

  if ( prev )
  {
    prev->next = new;
  }
  else
  {
    l->head = new;
  }      
}
```

So I can create two lists:

```
struct list a, b;
```

that I can order different ways by attaching different comparison functions:

```
int sort_ascending( const data_t a, const data_t b )
{
  ...
}

int sort_descending( const data_t a, const data_t b )
{
  ...
}

a.compar = sort_ascending;
b.compar = sort_descending;
```

You can build lookup tables that can execute a function based on one or more criteria, and adding new functionality is just a matter of writing the new functions and adding them to the table, rather than hacking the application logic itself:

```
void (*do_something[])( void ) = { do_A, do_B, do_C };

...

int x = get_some_value();
do_something[x]();
```